# Gallery lighbox for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gallery, lightbox

I have a html template showing a gallery lightbox and i want to add it in wordpress.

i try looking for a plugin similar but always the result is not like i want.
what im loking for is a way to add in wordpress backoffice simple gallery and show it in the template using a loop or forech but it's important to add the gallery in a page or post.

Here is my html code for the gallery :

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs position-bas">
                    <h4>diaporama</h4>
                    <div class="slider-diapo" id="thumbnails">
                        <a href="img/slider1.png" title="Slider 1">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider1.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                        <a href="img/slider2.png" title="Slider 2">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider2.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                         <a href="img/slider3.png" title="Slider 3">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider3.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                         <a href="img/slider4.png" title="Slider 4">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider4.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                         <a href="img/slider5.png" title="Slider 5">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider5.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                         <a href="img/slider6.png" title="Slider 6">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider6.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                         <a href="img/slider8.png" title="Slider 8">
                            <img class="img-light" src="img/slider8.png" alt="Slider 1">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: you want your  gallery to always show the same images?
you can do it with a simple shortcode
i cant understand your question maybe...

Comment: @vahid i want to use a forech to loop my galerie but I need a plugin or something else to upload images and just modify the link of the image and the atrribut title in my template code but in simple way for every page or post in my wordpress admin for exemple you go to page home you add a list of images after that go to your template and link your galerie name or id